# make label visible in loginpage from viewmodelpage

Tags: xamarin, label, visible

I log in and set the error label with the isvisible property to false, the problem I have is that I do the control from the viewmodels and therefore, in case of wrong login I have to make the label visible from the viewmodel, someone can help me on how to be able to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of achieving this using a DataBinding. But you should move your label logic to the ViewModel:

**Option A: Controlling the visibility using bool flags**

In your viewModel

```
private bool _isVisible;
public bool IsVisible
{
get => _isVisible;
set {
_isVisible=value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
}
}
```

And your XAML

```
<Label x:Name="errorLabel" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
```

Then you just change the `IsVisible` inside your login method

**Option B: Using converters**

This ways uses more code, but the code can be reused. We bind the `IsVisible` property to an Error String. If the string is empty (no error), then the label will be hidden

1. Create a converter. This converter will return true if the string is not an error

   ```
    public class ErrorStringToBool: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string errorString = value.ToString();
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorString);
        }
   ....
   ```

2. And declare it in your `App.xaml.cs`

   ```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ErrorStringToBool x:Key="errorStringToBool"/>
        ....
    </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
3. In your Viewmodel declare a string property that is `ErrorString`. I will skip this code
4. In your `Login.xaml`

   ```
   <Label x:Name="errorLabel" IsVisible="{Binding ErrorString, Converter={x:StaticResource errorStringToBool}}" />
   ```

Comment: If you want to go with the **Option B**, you should check Xamarin Community Toolkit [IsNotNullOrEmptyConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/isnotnulloremptyconverter). It's the same but withtout creating the converter. Just include the nuget